# C++: struct initialization in presence of constructor

Tags: c++

I have question on C++ behavior when initializing structures using a list.  For example, the following code behaves the same in C and C++.  The list initializes `x`:

```
struct X {
    int x;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct X xx = {0};    
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I add a constructor, I find out through testing that the constructor is called instead of the simple initialization of the `x` member:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct X {
    int x;
    X(int);
};

X::X(int i)
{
    cout << "X(int i)" << endl;
    x = i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct X xx = {0};

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
X(int i)
```

Is the behavior of C++ with an identical constructor (as above) to override the simple list initialization?  Giving my testing that is what appears to happen.

Thanks!

Comment: This code does not reveal what would happen if you called the constructor, nor what the value of xx.x is.  Google c++ constructor and see how to call a constructor.  If it was a class not a struct, the default is private so such initialization/assignment is impossible.

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett the constructor was called as you can see in the output.  Not sure what you are saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following syntax:

```
X xx = {0};
```

is just a form of [copy-list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). This has the effect of invoking the constructor of `X`, as you observed.

The name of this initialization comes from the fact that this looks like a list is being copied, but just the regular constructor is invoked. Note that this will only consider `implicit` constructors.

Also the *elaborated-type-specifier* `struct` is not necessary in c++, in the declaration of `xx`.

Note that if you don't provide a constructor such as `X(int)` (as you did in the first example), then the declaration of `xx` will instead do aggregate initialization.

Comment: So is the default for copy list initialization, without a constructor specified, to initialize the members of the struct in order?

Comment: Even without a user-provided constructor, the compiler will provide a constructor for you. Since the behavior of the default constructor is member wise initialization. yes.

Comment: "This has the effect of invoking the constructor of X" - only if the class has a user-provided constructor. Otherwise it is aggregate initialization and no constructor is called

Comment: @cigien If you don't declare `X::X(int)` yourself, I don't think such a constructor is declared or defined for you. Instead, if no constructors are user-declared, `X` becomes an aggregate class, and the syntax `X xx = {5};` becomes aggregate initialization. You can see there is no such constructor by trying: `X x(5);`. This fails, because there is no constructor to call. In C++20, this will work, but again, that's because it becomes aggregate initialization, which bypasses constructors.

Comment: @M.M So "class type with default constructor", specifically means user-provided default constructor?

Comment: @cigien No, that means any default constructor

Comment: @M.M Ok, I *think* I understand, thanks. Added a sentence to the answer, hopefully that helps.